# Quadratic trend line equation on plot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've seen many examples for displaying a linear trend line's equation on a plot, but haven't found one for displaying one of a higher order. I assumed it would be similar, but I keep getting errors. I have a feeling it has to do with not understanding the purpose of the z's in my print statement. Here is my code, thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


df=pd.read_csv('myfile', delimiter=',',  usecols=[1,4], names=['Time','Position'])

plt.figure(figsize=(9,6))
plt.suptitle('')

x=df['Time']
y=df['Position']
plt.subplot(1,1,1)
plt.tick_params(labelsize=6)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x,p(x),"r--")

plt.xlabel('Time (s)', fontsize=9)
plt.ylabel('Position (mm)', fontsize=9)
plt.title('13.087 Degree Incline', fontsize=10, weight='bold')
plt.legend( loc=2, prop={'size': 6})
plt.tight_layout()

print "y=%.6fx^2+%.6fx+(%.6f)"%(z[0],z[1])

plt.show()
```

edit:
when running in python2, I get

```
File "scriptname.py", line 27, in <module>
print "y=%.6fx^2+%.6fx+(%.6f)"%(z[0],z[1])
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

when running in python3 I get :

```
    File "scriptname.py", line 27
print "y=%.6fx^2+%.6fx+(%.6f)"%(z[0],z[1])
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle the error messages are pretty good at explaining what's wrong. 
In the string  `"y=%.6fx^2+%.6fx+(%.6f)"` you have 3 format specifiers, you later only provide 2 arguments (`%(z[0],z[1])`)

The solution is of course to supply to as many arguments as format specifiers.

```
print "y=%.6fx^2+%.6fx+(%.6f)"%(z[0],z[1],z[2])
```

In python3 you would eventually end up with the same error, once you use the print *function* `print(arg)` instead of of the print *statement* `print arg` as in python 2.

```
print ( "y=%.6fx^2+%.6fx+(%.6f)"%(z[0],z[1],z[2]) )
```